# <p:sticky> doesn't resize on window resize

Tags: jsf, primefaces, sticky, window-resize

I'm using [`<p:sticky>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/sticky.xhtml) with a menu. My problem is that it does not resize when the window is resized.

How can I make the `<p:sticky>` to resize as well when the window is resized?

Comment: The key appears to be that Primefaces calculates the width of the target element on initialization, i.e. when the page is loaded. After that it's a fixed number. I'm checking whether one can re-initialize this particular widget from the client-side, then you could hook that up to the page's resize event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so as I said in my comment above, the problem is that Primefaces only calculates the width of the target once, on initialization. After that it's a fixed number that doesn't change.

So what we have to do is to re-initialize the component. I've tried it out on the [Primefaces Showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/sticky.xhtml).

The following client-side Javascript *almost* does the trick:

```
foo = PF('widget_j_idt93');
foo.init(foo.cfg);
```

(Here "widget_j_idt93" is the `widgetVar` of the Primefaces component. Substitute your own as appropriate.)

What is missing is that Primefaces (quite correctly) thinks that the widget already *is* initialized. In order to un-initialize the widget, we can first remove all the element styles:

```
$("#tb").attr("style","")
```

(Where "#tb" is the selector of the target, i.e. your menu.)

So if you make a function that first removes the styles and then resets the widget, it should work.

Edit: [After looking at the client-side code of the Sticky component](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/sticky/sticky.js) I figured it out. You have to restore before you blank and initialize, and then you have to explicitly run the sticky-or-not call. **So this should be the solution:**

```
fixSticky = function() {
    var bla=PF('widget_j_idt93');
    bla.restore();
    bla.target.attr("style","");
    bla.init(bla.cfg);
    if($(window).scrollTop() > bla.initialState.top) {bla.fix();} else {bla.restore();}
}
```

Simply run this function (modified to your own widgetVar, or maybe with a parameter) whenever the page is resized.